# Winning conditions in a game not counting

Tags: python

This is my code for a slots type game in which the winning conditions for c and e are 3 of the same number and 3,6,9/9,6,3 respectively. When I run the simulations, these winning conditions don't show up when the variables are printed at the end. What mistake is in my code?

```
    TABLE = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    TABLE1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

    a=0
    b=0
    c=0
    d=0
    e=0
    for pp in range (100000):


rand1 = random.randint(0,9)
rand2 = random.randint(0,9)
rand3 = random.randint(0,9)

word1 = TABLE[rand1]
word2 = TABLE[rand2]
word3 = TABLE1[rand3]

print(word1, word2, word3)
if word1 > 8 or word2 > 8 or word3 > 8:
    a +=1
elif word1 == word2 or word1 == word3 or word2 == word3:
    b +=1
elif word1 == word2 and word2 == word3:
    c +=1
elif word1 <8 and word2 == word1 + 1 and word3 == word2 + 1:
    d +=1
elif word1 == 3 and word2 == 6 and word3 == 9 or word1 == 9 and word2 == 6 and word3 == 3:
    e +=1
```

print (a, b, c, d, e)

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand the question. However, I can see that `c += 1` will never be triggered, because if `word1 == word2 and word2 == word3` is true then so must the previous condition `word1 == word2 or word1 == word3 or word2 == word3`

Comment: The condition for `e` never triggers because any combination of numbers with a nine in it already triggered `a`. It sounds like you may want your `if` statements to be independent, since several can be true at once. If that's the case, don't use `elif`.

Comment: Because I want "e" to take priority over "a" as it is a better winning outcome and similarly with "c" having prio over "b", will the independent if statement do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you have structured your if statements causes some to be unreachable. I’ll go into detail why this is the case.

When running this code, the conditions C and E are never met. Let’s start with C, the condition for C is `word1 == word2 and word2 == word3`. Because this is located after condition B which has the check `word1 == word2 or ...`, condition C will never trigger.

For condition E there is a similar problem, in this case it conflicts with condition A. This condition  `word1 > 8 or word2 > 8 or word3 > 8` will equal to `True` if any of the words is higher than 8, given your table this can only be the number 9. This conflicts with condition E because it has the following check `... and word3 == 9 ...`. This means A will always be True before E is even checked as condition A will be True if any of the words is a 9.

Unto the solution.
In this instance it is possible to reorder your conditions to get the desired output.

```py
    if (word1 == 3 and word2 == 6 and word3 == 9) or (word1 == 9 and word2 == 6 and word3 == 3):
        e += 1
    elif word1 == word2 and word2 == word3:
        c += 1
    elif word1 == word2 or word1 == word3 or word2 == word3:
        b += 1
    elif word1 > 8 or word2 > 8 or word3 > 8:
        a += 1
    elif word1 < 8 and word2 == word1 + 1 and word3 == word2 + 1:
        d += 1
```

In this case I just moved up the conditions E and C, and it worked fine. I ran this code for 10000000 iterations, and this was my result.
A = 2140416, B = 2697247, C = 100362, D = 69684, E = 19912

Comment: wait u mean for condition e in the 3rd paragraph right?